# Setting two subject in JWT token generation in spring boot microservice

Tags: spring-boot, jwt, microservices

I am trying to generate a JWT token for my microservice . And that token will use my front-end application for service accessing. Here I am setting subject by adding my username. I need to add user id along with username. Below code I am using for generating Token by only adding subject "username".

My code is ,

```
protected String getToken(String encodedSecret, Users jwtUser){
    return Jwts.builder()
            .setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
            .setSubject(jwtUser.getUsername())
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, encodedSecret)
            .compact();
}
```

Here I need to add two subject username with userid. How I can add two subject here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply cannot have two or more claims with the same name:

> [**4.  JWT Claims**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4)
>
> The JWT Claims Set represents a JSON object whose members are the
> claims conveyed by the JWT.  The Claim Names within a JWT Claims Set
> MUST be unique; JWT parsers MUST either reject JWTs with duplicate
> Claim Names or use a JSON parser that returns only the lexically last
> duplicate member name [...]

However you can use another claim for the user id:

```java
return Jwts.builder()
           .setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
           .setSubject(jwtUser.getUsername())
           .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, encodedSecret)
           .claim("user-id", "id goes here")
           .compact();
```

---

> Can I add an object instead of a integer? Like JSON?

Yes, a claim value can be any arbitrary JSON value, but a claim name must be a string:

> [**2.  Terminology**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-2)
>
> [...]
>
> Claim Name
> The name portion of a claim representation. A Claim Name is
> always a string.**
>
> Claim Value
> The value portion of a claim representation. A Claim Value can be
> any JSON value.
>
> [...]

> [**3.  JSON Web Token (JWT) Overview**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-3)
>
> JWTs represent a set of claims as a JSON object that is encoded in a
> JWS and/or JWE structure.  This JSON object is the JWT Claims Set.
> [...] the JSON object consists of
> zero or more name/value pairs (or members), where the names are
> strings and the values are arbitrary JSON values.  These members are
> the claims represented by the JWT. [...]

So you could define a class like:

```java
class UserDetails {

    private Integer id;
    private List<String> roles;

    public UserDetails(Integer id, String... roles) {
        this.id = id;
        this.roles = Arrays.asList(roles);
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public UserDetails setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }

    public List<String> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public UserDetails setRoles(List<String> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
        return this;
    }
}
```

And then use as follows:

```java
return Jwts.builder()
           .setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
           .setSubject(jwtUser.getUsername())
           .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, encodedSecret)
           .claim("user-details", new UserDetails(1, "ROLE_1", "ROLE_2"))
           .compact();
```

It will produce the following payload:

```json
{
  "jti": "d65b83fd-fafb-4df4-9782-c4700c3c93ff",
  "sub": "joe.doe",
  "user-details": {
    "id": 1,
    "roles": [
      "ROLE_1",
      "ROLE_2"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Then how I can add additional information to this encoding. Suppose I need to add roles by adding its Ids like 1001,2001?

Comment: Can I add a object instead of a integer? like JSON ?

Comment: Yes, I found updated. I will try. Thank you for your response.